Can the C++ linker deduce symbol from function call without a function prototype
If I have a static library with implementations for some classes and functions, is it possible to link to it without a header file that declares the functions and classes implemented in the static library? Is the linker able to deduce the symbol from the function call only?
Problem is the classes in the static library call functions from a header-only library (implementations are in the header files), so If I include my header-only library in the code that uses the static library, I end up with two implementations for those functions.
Thank you very much
I tried adding my static libs to the linker inputs (visual studio) and simply call the functions, it didn't like that.
And when I include the header files, I get " already defined in " error

Functions defined in a header file should be declared as inline. If you do that the poblem goes away. In other words you are trying to solve the wrong problem, fix the header file only library.

You can either declare the functions in your source module as extern types, as would be done in an ordinary header. Or change the header and move the implementations into a normal C/CPP source file.

A "header" that causes multiple definitions when used in several files might have a *.hpp name, but it's certainly not a "header"...

It was a C feature to be able to call functions without prototypes. C++ linker can't do that because names of symbols are dependant on types of arguments AND on on location of entity (namespace, memeber of class, etc). Main reason for this is parametric polymorphism permitted in C++, aka function overloading.
If a header-only library uses external dependencies that are static library entities, you have to provide it a header with prototypes, or hide implementation behind a bridge pattern. It stops being purely header-only in either case.

Great thanks, that makes sense.
Just out of curiosity, what information is it that is not known at compile time. Both the input argument types and the location of the call are known at compile time, right?

@mhdbabayi the factual parameters are known at compile time of  calling unit. The formal parameters  and location of function are known at time of compiling their "home" units, it may not match perfectly. C had only values and pointers and function name. C++ got references,  rvalue references, it might be static class-type or base class-type, the location of function might be not in global namespace but somehow visible, it may belong to one of base classes while caller belong to derived, etc..

@mhdbabayi E.g. caller is a foo in a namespace A, it calls a function bar, perhaps no arguments are used. Is it a function with no arguments,with all default arguments, or a variadic with no arguments? Is bar located in namespace A, in global namespace? Perhaps even both.
